# Drupal 7 custom form module

Tags: drupal-7, form-api

My form using custom module is not appearing on my contact us page.I created my `.module` file and `.info` file and then active the module as well. Following is the code I had included in my `.module` file

```
function custom_form_module_form($form,&$form_state) {
$form['name'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
);
$form['company'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
);
$form['phone'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
);
$form['email'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
);
$form['message'] = array(
'#type' => 'textfield',
);
return $form; 
}
```

and in my template.php file

```
function custom_form_module_form_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
$items['custom_form_module_form'] = array(
'render element' => 'form',
'template' => 'page--contact-us',
'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'escorts').'/templates');
return $items;
}
```

and in my `page--contact-us.tpl.php` I used the following line to call separate fields of a form but its not working.

```
<?php echo drupal_render($form['name']); ?>
```

"here `custom_form_module=my module name` and `page--contact-us.tpl.php=my template file` and `escorts=my theme name`"

Comment: And the problem is... !

Comment: form is not appearing on my contact us page @muhammad, I tried to get the "name" field here

Answer (score 0):

To print the form in the contact page, you may not use `template.php`.

Simply:

```
$my_form = drupal_get_form('custom_form_module_form');
print drupal_render($my_form);
```

**Update**

Change the form markup from from your `template.php`

```
function theme_my_form_1($form) {
    $vars['element'] = $form;

    $markup = '';
    $markup .= '<div id="form-name-wrapper">'
        . drupal_render($form['name'])
        . '</div>';
    // continue altering the markup

    $vars['element']['#children'] = $output;
    return theme_form($vars);
}
```

Then, in your `.tpl.php` file:

```
$my_form = drupal_get_form('custom_form_module_form');
print theme_my_form_1($my_form);
```

Comment: Thanku @Muhammad, but I want individual fields in order to theme them separately. Is my code correct?